# Are “stockpots” concentrated stock packs in the refrigerated section of the supermarket?

Tags: storage-method, stock, convenience-foods

Will mass-produced stockpots (gelled stock concentrate) be found in the refrigerated section of the supermarket or in the section where stock cubes are?

Comment: What do you mean by "stockpots"? I only know the term as the big steel vessel in which you cook stock. Also, I am a bit unsure how good this question fits the site. Each supermarket can place any product wherever they want.

Comment: In which country/region are you shopping?

Comment: @rumtscho it is some marketing name for liquid/jelly stock in a little plastic container

Comment: Ask one of the employees where (and if) they can be found. Not every store sells those things.

Comment: Watch out with those Knorr Stockpots, they’re more gravy browning & salt than stock. If you want decent instant stock, look for Kallo.

Comment: @unlisted I guess it's not just me that found them disappointing then (I normally use veg bouillon or homemade veg/chicken stock, either way low salt, high flavour)

Comment: @ChrisH they’re little more than gelatinised oxo cubes;)) I bought some to see and they lasted months whilst I could find the right dishes to hide them in.

Comment: @unlisted for comparison: Per prepared 100ml kallo Organic Chicken Stock Cubes have .9g salt. knorr stock pot per prepared 100ml has 0.83g salt. The Knorr is 63% concentrated stock, the Kallo has 1% 'chicken powder' and 'natural chicken flavour'.

Comment: @Spagirl - you may indeed be right - but have you ever tasted them for direct comparison?

Comment: @unlisted I don't much use either type of product. Back when I did, I found Kallo stock cubes to be unremarkable and extremely difficult to dissolve by comparison to their OXO equivalents. I have used the Stockpots occasionally in soups and found them perfectly unobjectionable. I just find it a slightly strange to condemn one for being all salt and colour while praising another than literally has salt as the highest volume ingredient. On the whole the Kallo ingredients are 'cleaner' so I might try their Stock Pot version if I find myself in need of that kind of product.

Comment: @Spagirl - I actually use the Kallo low salt version, which is 0.1, but my main complaint on the Knorr stockpots is the gravy browning. One can kill a delicate colour in a dish. Oxo I won't touch with a barge pole. They just taste of Oxo, unmistakably. I stopped using them 35 years ago, long before I ever actually cared about the ingredients list. I eventually landed on the Kallo because they don't impart a 'signature' compared to most of the others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You sometimes can buy refrigerated stock, but the concentrated "Knorr Stock Pots" that I tried when they were on offer are shelf stable and sold with the stock cubes and powders.  But products are different in different places, so I don't know in your case.

As a general rule, and why I decided to make this an answer and not a comment: If your supermarket has an online shop, search for the product in that and look for which section they're in: [Sainsbury's (UK), where I probably bought them](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/product/stock/knorr-vegetable-stock-pot-4x28g) lists them under "Food cupboard | Cooking ingredients & oils | Stocks" and not under "Dairy, Eggs, and Chilled" (a bit of catch-all category for miscellaneous stuff sold in fridges, plus eggs which are usually near the milk but not refrigerated here).  This gives a clue as to that supermarket's thinking, which tends to be consistent between online and in-store categories